# i have tried to rum this procedure but looks like it doesnt comile

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace procedure nestedTableColumnDemo is
    --i have tried to create netsed table  
    TYPE address_nest1 is TABLE OF varchar2(50);    

    --using varchar i tried to create a table but it gives an error i have no idea why.
    var1 varchar2(100); 
begin 

   --this is where i created the table using a variable var1
   var1:='create table customer_info(name varchar2(50),postal_address address_nest1) nested table postal_address store as postal_address_tab';        
   execute immediate var1;

end nestedTableColumnDemo;

execute nestedTableColumnDemo;
```

When I try to execute this it shows an error but no table is created.

Comment: Which error Oracle gives you?

Comment: it says invalid datatype the exact error is:ORA-00902: invalid datatype
ORA-06512: at "CS457_16610.NESTEDTABLECOLUMNDEMO", line 8
ORA-06512: at line 1
00902. 00000 -  "invalid datatype"

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address_nest1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10)
/   

 create or replace procedure nestedTableColumnDemo is   --i have tried to create netsed table  
    var1 varchar2(200);--using varchar i tried to create a table but it gives an error i have no idea why.
    begin 
    var1:='create table customer_info
    (name varchar2(50),
    postal_address address_nest1) 
    nested table postal_address store as postal_address_tab'; --this is where i created the table using a variable var1
    execute immediate var1;

    end nestedTableColumnDemo;
    /

    execute nestedTableColumnDemo;
    /
```

This Works.

Comment: yeah but it says invalid data type.It probably must be the postal_address address_nest1 which it is not recognising

Comment: Try to create Type address_nest1 outside of procedure.
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address_nest1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10)
/ then run procedure

Comment: what difference does it make?? just out of curiousity

Comment: To create any table consiting of f.e TYPE, This TYPE MUST be existing in database. This Type it's only existing in Your procedure.